# Split a string into individual characters in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi I have an input as

```
ID  data
1   hello
2   sql
```

The desired output being

```
ID  RowID  Chars
1    1     H
1    2     e
1    3     l
1    4     l
1    5     o
2    1     s
2    2     q
2    3     l
```

My approach so far being

```
Declare @t table(ID  INT IDENTITY , data varchar(max))
Insert into @t Select 'hello' union all select 'sql'
--Select * from @t
;With CteMaxlen As(
Select MaxLength = max(len(data)) from @t)
, Num_Cte AS
(     
      SELECT 1 AS rn
      UNION ALL
      SELECT rn +1 AS rn 
      FROM Num_Cte 
      WHERE rn <(select MaxLength from CteMaxlen)
)
-- Shred into individual characters
, Get_Individual_Chars_Cte AS
( 
      SELECT  
            ID
            ,Row_ID =ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION by ID Order by ID)
            ,chars               
      FROM @t,Num_Cte
      CROSS APPLY( SELECT SUBSTRING((select data from  @t),rn,1)  AS chars) SplittedChars       
)

Select * from Get_Individual_Chars_Cte
```

The query is not working at all with an exception being

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

Edit :

I found my answer

```
;with Get_Individual_Chars_Cte AS
( 
   SELECT 
        ID,
        Row_ID =ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION by ID Order by ID) 
        ,SUBSTRING(Data,Number,1) AS [Char]--,

FROM @t  
INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values ON
 Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(Data)
 AND type='P'

)

Select * from Get_Individual_Chars_Cte
```

Help needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
  select ID,
         substring(data, 1, 1) as Chars,
         stuff(data, 1, 1, '') as data,
         1 as RowID
  from @t
  union all
  select ID,
         substring(data, 1, 1) as Chars,
         stuff(data, 1, 1, '') as data,
         RowID + 1 as RowID
  from cte
  where len(data) > 0
)
select ID, RowID, Chars
from cte
order by ID, RowID
```

Comment: I actually answerd my own question in the Edit part mentioned in teh questioned body since I am having less reputation point. But thanks for the answer and I will accept your's but mine is working fine too. I request, since you have more reputation, is it possible for you to take out my answer and paste in the answer part? If so, please do the needful if you feel that my answer is euqally correct as yours.

Comment: @aditi - You should be able to answer your own questions. There might be a time limit (8 hours?) for users with rep under 100. Can't find it in the FAQ but I remember reading about that. You can **accept** your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but it's worth posting a purely set-based solution. Using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) you can do this:

```
Declare @t table(ID  INT IDENTITY , data varchar(max))
Insert into @t Select 'hello' union all select 'sql';

SELECT ID, Row_ID = position, [char] = token 
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(data,1);
```

**Returns:**

```
ID  Row_ID  char
--- ------- --------
1   1       h
1   2       e
1   3       l
1   4       l
1   5       o
2   1       s
2   2       q
2   3       l
```