# Find chars in any order in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a datatable in sql server 2005 containing words in spanish. I have stored each word in a row.
Given a char array, I would like to find all the words which contains those characters, no mather in wich order they appear. For example, "avi" shoul match "avion" and also "iva". Is it possible?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you want to match ALL chars? Should "vi" or "avxi" be returned?

Comment: Hello:
Yes, I want to get all the words containing the predicate, no matter in which order they appear.

Comment: Does the word have to contain every character
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is split and pivot and then join.

So avi becomes three rows in a letters table:

```
a
v
i
```

Then join to the word list with `INNER JOIN ON CHARINDEX(letter, word) > 0`

Use `GROUP BY word`

with `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM letters)`

In this example, I just picked up and modified a cte from here [Split a string into individual characters in Sql Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367283/split-a-string-into-individual-characters-in-sql-server-2005) to avoid having to fool around with a numbers table (but I normally would probably use a numbers table to do my pivot).

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67103/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-10199927-find-chars-in-any-order-in-sql-server

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (search varchar(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('avi');

DECLARE @words AS TABLE (word varchar(100));
INSERT INTO @words VALUES ('avion'), ('iva'), ('name');
with cte as
(
  select substring(search, 1, 1) as letter,
         stuff(search, 1, 1, '') as search,
         1 as RowID
  from @t
  union all
  select substring(search, 1, 1) as letter,
         stuff(search, 1, 1, '') as search,
         RowID + 1 as RowID
  from cte
  where len(search) > 0
)
,letters AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT letter FROM cte
)
SELECT words.word
FROM letters
INNER JOIN @words AS words
    ON CHARINDEX(letter, word) > 0
GROUP BY words.word
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM letters)
```

Comment: Hello:
I'll try your solution this evening, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your answers. Finally, I solved it by creating an assembly inside Sql Server capable of evaluating regular expressions.
Here is the article used as base:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%a%' AND word LIKE '%v%'AND word LIKE '%i%'
```

This consumes "a lot" resources, so you should not use it on >1M rows (depending on your server).

Comment: yes, if you read what I wrote... I don't know what the purpose it, but if it is just for one select...