# How many letters have been used per day since 07/12/16 to 15/05/17

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a report where I am counting how many times each letter used as personalisation with crystal alphabets on each day.

```
  SELECT 

   [Order]
  ,[Style]
  ,[Text]  

  FROM [Item Personalisation] as 
  OP
   INNER JOIN  [Order Header] AS 
  OH 
  ON OH.[Order Guid]=OP.[Owner Header GuID]
  WHERE [Personalisation] ='CRYSTALS'
  AND [Order Date]>= '2016-12-07T00:00:00.000' AND 
  [Order Date] <= '2016-12-07T00:00:00.000'
```

If I run above query I am getting below results set.

```
 Order       Style      Text
 23099557   CRYSTALS    CM
 23104712   CRYSTALS    HJC
 23107055   CRYSTALS    IMO
 23107904   CRYSTALS    JH
 23108782   CRYSTALS    GAB
 22320464   CRYSTALS    ZLR
```

So I am running only for one day but I need results by day till 15/05/17 and want to know how many times each letter as been used date wise and results set is something like below table.

```
              07/12/2016    08/12/2016  09/12/2016  10/12/2016 -- 15/05/2017
 Letter A               
 Letter B               
 Letter C
 - to  - 
 Letter Z
```

Please help.

Comment: Assuming you are using SQL Server you could use PIVOT or you could use aggregation with a case statement. Is the letter identifier the Text column?

Comment: Yes, I am using sql. letter identifier is text column.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367283/split-a-string-into-individual-characters-in-sql-server-2005 to split the text into rows for each letter keeping teh order date on the record then case dates to pivot or use dynamic SQL to pivot. as @Bee_Riii hilighted below.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun.  This is a dynamic pivot (many examples) where the the source is unpivoted by date, letter via a cross apply which uses an ad-hoc tally table.

Just to keep it square, we tossed in a union all to ensure all 26 letters were listed.

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2016-12-07'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-05-15'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(OrderDate) 
                                    From  Yourtable 
                                    Where OrderDate between @Date1 and @Date2 
                                    Order by 1 
                                    For XML Path('')
                                  ),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select *
From (
        Select A.OrderDate
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Top (len(A.Text)) substring(A.Text,Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),1),1 
                         From  master..spt_values 
                     ) B (Letter,Cnt)
         Where OrderDate between '''+convert(varchar(10),@Date1,112)+''' and '''+convert(varchar(10),@Date2,112)+'''
           and Letter like ''[a-zA-Z]''
        Union All
        Select Top (26) '''+convert(varchar(10),@Date1,112)+''',char(Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)+64),null  From master..spt_values 
     ) A
Pivot (count(Cnt) For [OrderDate] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p
Order By Letter
'

Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

**If it helps, the following is generated SQL.**

```
Select *
From (
        Select A.OrderDate
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Top (len(A.Text)) substring(A.Text,Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),1),1 
                         From  master..spt_values 
                     ) B (Letter,Cnt)
         Where OrderDate between '20161207' and '20170515'
           and Letter like '[a-zA-Z]'
        Union All
        Select Top (26) '20161207',char(Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)+64),null  From master..spt_values 
     ) A
Pivot (count(Cnt) For [OrderDate] in ([2016-12-07],[2016-12-08],[2016-12-09],[2016-12-10]) ) p
Order By Letter
```

> **EDIT - UPDATED FOR ACTUAL TABLES AND FIELD NAMES**

There is what the static version should look like

```
Select * 
 From ( 
       Select oh.[Order Date] 
             ,b.*
        From  [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Internet Order Personalisation] A 
        INNER JOIN [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Feelunique Trading$Internet Order Header] AS OH ON OH.[Order Guid]=a.[Owner Header GuID] 
        Cross Apply (
                      Select Top (len(A.[Personalisation Text])) substring(A.[Personalisation Text],Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),1),1 
                       From  master..spt_values 
                     ) B (Letter,Cnt)
        Where [Order Date] between '20161207' and '20161209' 
          and Letter like '[a-zA-Z]%' 
          and [Personalisation Style] ='CRYSTALS' 
        Union All 
        Select Top (26) '20161207',char(Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)+64),null From master..spt_values 
     ) A 
Pivot (count(cnt) For [Order Date] in ([2016-12-07],[2016-12-08],[2016-12-09])) P 
Order By letter 
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: select *
From (
        Select A.OrderDate
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A   , what is b.* here ??/

Comment: @Giridhar B is just an alias of the Cross Apply which is essentially an ad-hoc tally table which is used to unpivot the string

Comment: I am getting this error :   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @Giridhar I'm getting consistant results (no errors) between both the dynamic and static versions.   What modifications did you make?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here and don't how to write full code in one box

Comment: @Giridhar Give me a moment

Comment: @Giridhar OK, I see what you did.  You added extra fields in the top subquery.   The PIVOT should be limited to only the required fields X,Y and Value   ..  I will update my answer

Comment: Because I am joining two tables as order date and text is different tables and  order number in common.

Comment: @Giridhar That is fine, but the Pivot only cares about Order Date, Letter and Count.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you very much super star.

Comment: @Giridhar Happy to help, and thanks for the grin  :)

Answer (score 0):

[NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) is a pure T-SQL function designed for ***exactly*** this type of task.

This will create an alphabet:

```
SELECT letter = token FROM dbo.NGrams8k('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',1);
```

Here's some sample data and logic we can use to count characters by day.

```
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE 
(
  txt varchar(8000),
  someDate date
);

INSERT @yourtable (txt, somedate)
VALUES 
('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.', '20161207'),
('To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.', '20161208'),
('Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.', '20161209'),
('Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.','20161210');
WITH 
yourtxt AS
(
  SELECT SomeDate, letter = token 
  FROM @yourtable
  CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(txt, 1)
),
alphabet AS
(
  SELECT letter = token
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',1)
),
matrix AS
(
  SELECT t.someDate, a.letter, total = COUNT(t.letter) 
  FROM alphabet a
  LEFT JOIN yourtxt t ON a.letter = t.letter
  GROUP BY t.someDate, a.letter
)
SELECT * 
FROM matrix;
```

That code will get you this:

```
someDate   letter 
---------- -------
2016-12-07 A      
2016-12-08 A      
2016-12-09 A      
2016-12-10 A      
2016-12-07 B      
2016-12-08 B      
2016-12-10 B      
2016-12-07 C      
2016-12-08 C      
2016-12-09 C      
....
2016-12-08 X
2016-12-10 X
2016-12-07 Y
2016-12-08 Y
2016-12-09 Y
2016-12-10 Y
```

A couple things to note: I'm in America so I used the standard date format in my logic (yyyymmdd) but output the dates in the format you're using. Also notice that there's some days where a letters is not used at all that date (e.g. x, z). Lastly, I'm only doing sample data through 20161210 for brevity.

The last thing we need to do is pivot your data using this logic:

```
WITH 
yourtxt AS
(
  SELECT SomeDate, letter = token 
  FROM @yourtable
  CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(txt, 1)
),
alphabet AS
(
  SELECT letter = token
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',1)
),
matrix AS
(
  SELECT t.someDate, a.letter, total = COUNT(t.letter) 
  FROM alphabet a
  LEFT JOIN yourtxt t ON a.letter = t.letter
  GROUP BY t.someDate, a.letter
)
SELECT 
  matrix.letter,
  ISNULL(MAX(CASE matrix.someDate WHEN '20161207' THEN total END),0) AS [07/12/2016],
  ISNULL(MAX(CASE matrix.someDate WHEN '20161208' THEN total END),0) AS [08/12/2016],
  ISNULL(MAX(CASE matrix.someDate WHEN '20161209' THEN total END),0) AS [09/12/2016],
  ISNULL(MAX(CASE matrix.someDate WHEN '20161210' THEN total END),0) AS [10/12/2016]
FROM matrix
GROUP BY matrix.letter;
```

That code returns:

```
letter  07/12/2016  08/12/2016  09/12/2016  10/12/2016
------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A       11          19          16          17
B       2           2           0           3
C       7           11          12          10
D       11          15          8           7
E       23          35          28          20
F       4           6           0           2
G       0           5           5           2
H       7           10          17          11
I       11          9           6           13
J       0           0           0           0
K       2           3           2           4
L       6           9           6           7
M       2           8           8           4
N       11          14          14          18
O       26          23          13          21
P       7           7           6           6
Q       0           0           0           0
R       9           17          9           10
S       6           10          13          8
T       15          17          18          25
U       9           5           7           12
V       6           3           0           1
W       5           2           5           11
X       0           3           0           1
Y       10          4           8           6
Z       0           0           0           0
```

You can learn more about NGrams8K in this article: [Nasty Fast N-Grams (Part 1): Character-Level NGrams](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/)

Comment: Hi Alan, I am joining two tables as  order date is one table and text is an another table but order number is same so I am joining both on it. My 2 tables names are  [Item Personalisation]  and [Order Header] and fields are order date , text .Can you put this code with this tables and fields as an example so will do the rest.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know which tables have which values and assume your join returns 1 record per use, I also assume the dates are fixed.  I personally prefer a case statement like below.  I've only done 2 columns but it should give you the idea.

```
SELECT  [Text],
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN [Order Date] >= '20160712'
                     AND [Order Date] < '20160713'
                     THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
            ) AS [20160712],
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN [Order Date] >= '20160713'
                     AND [Order Date] < '20160714'
                     THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
            ) AS [20160713]
FROM    [Item Personalisation] AS [OP]
    INNER JOIN [Order Header] AS [OH]
        ON     [OH].[Order Guid] = [OP].[Owner Header GuID]
WHERE   [Personalisation] = 'CRYSTALS'
        AND [Order Date]  >= '20161207'
        AND [Order Date]  <= '20161215'
GROUP BY [Text];
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason its not counting and I want to count how may times A ,B C to Z used  per day.

Comment: I think this is missing the method of evaluating the [text] for each letter and then grouping the A, B, C... Z together in the 26 rows (assuming American/English alphabet)

Comment: If it needs an output of the literal alphabet rather than the output of the text column then we would need a lookup or to build a case expression to do that.  When you say it's not counting, what output are you getting?  Are you getting just a 1 or a 0?  Did you copy the code exactly?  I notice your original query had the same date for both conditions.